# Custom Activity for String Replace

Tags: string, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, str-replace, sharepoint-designer

In SharePoint 2010 designer, there is no direct option to replace the string with some other values. but in 2013, this is available. Is there any option to make this activity? I a column which is saving user names separated with semicolon. I need to replace this semicolon with `<br/>` tag. Please suggest me if there is any solution on this

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1021217/Workflow-SharePoint-SharePoint-Online-custom) article for a step by step process of creating a Custom Action to do what you want which is not possible in OOTB custom actions.